# Subscript out of range while setting the range

Tags: excel, vba

By the line 
Set srchrange = Workbooks(wipreport).Worksheets("1. WIP report").Range("B15:B")

I got the error Subscript out of range. wipreport is chosen above from the file. The workbook for sure has the Sheet "1. WIP report". I copied it. Workbooks BPM-Tool is already opened but I have no error by this line of code. 
I can not even try if vlookup works.

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select WIP Report"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        'Store in fullpath variable
        wipreport = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With


Workbooks.Open wipreport


Dim lookFor As Range
Dim srchrange As Range

Set lookFor = Workbooks("BPM-Tool.xlsm").Worksheets("BPM-Report").Cells(10, 2)

Set srchrange = Workbooks(wipreport).Worksheets("1. WIP report").Range("B15:B")

    lookFor.Offset(0, 317).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchrange, 18, False)
```

Comment: `"B15:B"` is not a valid range address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select WIP Report"
        .ButtonName = "OK"
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        'Store in fullpath variable
        wipreport = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wipreport)


Dim lookFor As Range
Dim srchrange As Range

Set lookFor = Workbooks("BPM-Tool.xlsm").Worksheets("BPM-Report").Cells(10, 2)

Set srchrange = wb.Worksheets("1. WIP report").Range("B15:B1000")

    lookFor.Offset(0, 317).Value = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchrange, 18, False)
```

`wipreport` is a String not a Workbook object, that's why you are getting an error.

Comment: Thank You, but now I get Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Same one. 
"This issue may occur if one or more of the cells in an array (range of cells) contain a character string that is set to contain more than 911 characters." it may be the case I think

Comment: Try the Edited ans

Comment: Now it works, but I need to define kind of dynamic range. I will count the rows and then use variable.  Second thing is that my vlookup doesnt work It searches only for the first line. Do You think I should use some kind of loop?

Comment: Maybe try posting Another question once your this code is working.

Comment: I wish I could, but Im not allowed to post more posts :(

Answer (score 0):

**Workbooks.Open** takes the full file name e.g. *C:\temp\myfile.xlsx*

**Workbooks()** takes file name only e.g. *myfile.xlsx*

You can use this code to get the workbook object and then use it:

```
' Get the workbook object
Dim wk As Workbook
Set wk = Workbooks.Open(wipreport)

' Use the workbook object
wk.Worksheets("1. WIP report").Range ("B15:B")
```

Comment: Thank You but now  I get Runtime Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error”.  
"This issue may occur if one or more of the cells in an array (range of cells) contain a character string that is set to contain more than 911 characters."
It may be this case. Mine has 2500 rows